# pip install cmd but modules not found in PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, pip

So, I have Pycharm and pip up to date, and after installing any module with pip install, no matter where I install it (*/current_python_project) or somewhere else (*\python310\lib\site-packages)...

When I pip install let's say pandas, and then try

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

console says: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

This happens with other packages here the package is installed but modules or ".py" files form installation, are not found.

Thank you!

I tried installing in different folders and changing virtual environment setting to all possible combinations but yet, I still can't fix the problem...

Checked docents of "answers" to similar problems

Also I checked one more answer here it says I have to install in env/bin/python but I searched for all folders containing "env" and apparently I don't have this folder....

Comment: You have multiple versions of Python installed on your system.  `pip` installed the matplotlib module for one version of Python, but PyCharm is configured to use a different version.

Comment: Update your PyCharm configuration to use the same version of Python as `pip`.  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following instructions:

```
python -m pip install – upgrade pip
pip install pandas
pip install matplotlib
```

Or you can try following instructios:

open cmd, and type "where python". Once you have opened the Python folder, browse and open the Scripts folder and copy its location. Also verify that the folder contains the pip file.Now open the Scripts directory in the command prompt using the cd command and the location that you copied previously.Now install the library using pip install matplotlib command. If it looks complicated please follow this link, they show with illustrations: https://blog.finxter.com/fixed-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-matplotlib/