unable to install pip and pip packages on pycharm community version, how to install pip packages on pycharm?
click install packaging toolerror description
I am very new to python and pycharm
I was unable to install pip amd pip packages in pycharm community version on windows
I run pip install cowsay,
prompt error  pip install cowsay ^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
I have been reading similar questions and anwsers on stackoverflow
I tried the official troubleshooting hereto add interpreter in pycahrm setting but i can only find python3 as interpreter, cannot find pip related file to be added as interpreter
I also tried this post's method "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74393492/pip-install-cmd-but-modules-not-found-in-pycharm", it prompt error as SyntaxError.
even tried this method, it would not work
also tried sudo apt install python3-pip, prompt error as SyntaxError: invalid syntax
I figured it could be something wrong with my virtual environment but cannot find where to fix it.

Avoid using images in question. Please update question with code/error only before proceeding.

Those look like Python errors. You seem to be in a Python interactive session (a REPL), you are supposed to run those commands in a regular terminal with the system shell (like what you get when opening up a new terminal)

You can try deactivating your venv and running the next command:
python -m ensurepip

After that, activate your venv and run:
(venv) PS D:\your path> d:\your path\venv\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

You can find more solutions via this link
P.S.: Quick tip! We've all been beginners once, and dealing with common issues is totally normal :) Don't hesitate to ask questions, but remember to dig a bit deeper into your research next time. It's all part of getting stronger and smarter!

You can manage these packages using the builtin manager:

